# Search a word in FilePath and extract the file path from left to right based on First Match

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to **extract the path from left to right based on the first match from left to right but only with the Folder name and not with the file name**:

```
string numberToFind = "99999";

string filePath = "\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_99999_PayRoll data\Folder 99999\JanSlip.pdf";

int resultIndex = data.LastIndexOf(numberToFind);
if(resultIndex!=-1)
{
   data = data.Substring(0,resultIndex);
}
Output - \\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_
```

**Expected Output :**

> "\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder
> 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_99999_PayRoll data

As you can see that the output I am getting is not matching with the 'Expected Output'.

Please note that I only want to `match the numberToFind on the folder level` and extract the path from left to right based on the first match but if there is no match found on the folder level then I want to return the whole path. **For eg:**

```
string numberToFind = "99999";
    
string filePath = "\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\99999_JunePayslips.pdf";

Expected output : \\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\99999_JunePayslips.pdf
```

Comment: Which  .NET version are you using?

Comment: @silkfire I am using .NET 6. 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path.GetDirectoryName` will get us the path without the last segment, and return `null` for the root. And `Path.GetFileName` will get us the last segment.

So you can use the following iterative approach:

- Take the directory of the given path and store it in `toSearch`.
- While that is not null:

  - Check whether the last segment contains the value you are searching.
  - If so, store the current `toSearch` in `found`
  - Chop off the next directory segment, and loop.
- Return `found` if we have it, otherwise the original `path`.

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GKNnR2), note the fiddle uses `/` separators because it's on Linux/Unix.

```
private static string FindPathByDirectory(string path, string toFind)
{
    var toSearch = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string? found = null;
    while (toSearch != null)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(toSearch).Contains(toFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            found = toSearch;
        toSearch = Path.GetDirectoryName(toSearch);
    }
    return found ?? path;
}
```

To go in a right-to-left direction is simpler, you can just bail out as soon as you find it.

```
private static string FindPathByDirectory(string path, string toFind)
{
    var toSearch = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    while (toSearch != null)
    {
        if (Path.GetFileName(toSearch).Contains(toFind, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return toSearch;
        toSearch = Path.GetDirectoryName(toSearch);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

so. you can do for each file in derectory and collect that once which returns true.

you can do only on filename to match
P.S.

```
Directory.GetParent(filePath) 
//OR
Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
```

will give you folder where this file located

```
void Main()
{
    string numberToFind = "99999";
    string filePath = @"\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_99999_PayRoll data\Folder 99999\JanSlip.pdf";
    //this logic return true/false
    //check all path parts to match
    filePath.Split('\\').ToList().Any(s=> s.Contains(numberToFind)).Dump();
    //check only filename to match
    filePath.Split('\\').Last().Dump().Contains(numberToFind).Dump();
    //check only folders - skip file
    filePath.Split('\\').ToList().SkipLast(1).Any(s=> s.Contains(numberToFind)).Dump();
    
}
```

**UPDATE** for second request:
multiple parameters on list of files

```
void Main()
{
    string numberToFind = "99999";
    string[] numbers = new string[] { "22222", "55555" };
    string filePath = @"\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_99999_PayRoll data\Folder 99999\JanSlip.pdf";
    //assume you have Directory.GetFiles (path) which will return list of files - matching your UNC path
    string[] filePathlist = new String[]
    {
        @"\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_99999_PayRoll data\Folder 99999\JanSlip.pdf",
        @"\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_22222_PayRoll data\Folder 99999\JanSlip.pdf",
        @"\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_55555_PayRoll data\Folder 99999\JanSlip.pdf"
    };
    
    var lstResult = new List<(string,string)>(); 
    
    //check all path parts to match
    Console.WriteLine(filePath.Split('\\').ToList().Any(s=> s.Contains(numberToFind)));
    //check only filename to match
    Console.WriteLine(filePath.Split('\\').Last().Dump().Contains(numberToFind));
    //check only folders - skip file
    Console.WriteLine(filePath.Split('\\').ToList().SkipLast(1).Any(s => s.Contains(numberToFind)));
    //arreay on array
    Console.WriteLine(filePath.Split('\\').ToList().SkipLast(1).Any(s => numbers.Any(b => s.Contains(b))));

    filePathlist.ToList().ForEach(file =>
    {
        
        if (file.Split('\\').Distinct().SkipLast(1)
            .Any(pathsegment => numbers.Any(n => pathsegment.Contains(n))))
        {
            lstResult.Add((file.Split('\\').Last(), Path.GetDirectoryName(file)));
        }

    });
    Console.WriteLine(lstResult);
}
```

result of example
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to create a method which takes 2 parameters and just return the expected output? I am confused with what to use from your answer

Comment: Sorry I am not clear with your answer that how it will return the expected output.

Comment: yes. but that would be check against array. i will add example for you (list preferable)  instead of another parameter

Comment: Getting error on Dump. Its not available to me

Comment: please replace OBJECT.Dump() with Console.Wirteline(OBJECT) (.Dump() used in linqpad - very helpful tool)

Comment: fixed error and add result to show output as List<Tuple> - filename and path

Answer (score 1):

You have to search the last directory separator char once you've found the number. And you can use `Path.GetDirectoryName` to ignore the file name at the end:

```
void Main()
{
    string numberToFind = "99999";
    string filePath = @"\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_99999_PayRoll data\Folder 99999\JanSlip.pdf";
    
    string result = FindPath(filePath, numberToFind); 
}

public static string FindPath(string filePath, string numberToFind)
{
    string pathWithoutFileName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
    int index = pathWithoutFileName.LastIndexOf(numberToFind);
    if(index == -1)
    {
        return filePath;
    }
    
    string pathToken = pathWithoutFileName[..index];
    int indexOfNextPathSeparator = pathToken.LastIndexOf(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    if(indexOfNextPathSeparator == -1)
    {
        return filePath;
    }
    
    return pathToken[..indexOfNextPathSeparator];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method should to the trick:

```
private static string GetDirectoryPathUpUntilFirstMatch(in ReadOnlySpan<char> path, in ReadOnlySpan<char> value)
{
    var fileDirectoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    var valueMatchPosition = fileDirectoryPath.IndexOf(value);
    if (valueMatchPosition == -1)
    {
        return path.ToString();
    }

    var nextPathSeparatorMatchPosition = fileDirectoryPath.Slice(valueMatchPosition).LastIndexOf('\\');
    if (nextPathSeparatorMatchPosition == -1)
    {
        return fileDirectoryPath.ToString();
    }

    return fileDirectoryPath.Slice(0, valueMatchPosition + nextPathSeparatorMatchPosition + 1).ToString();
}
```

Usage:

```
public void Main()
{
    const string numberToFind = "99999";
    const string filePath = @"\\mydomain.com\TestEnv\MyApp\ImportantFiles\Phase 1\Employee\Folder 1\Folder 1.2\Folder 1.2.1_99999_PayRoll data\Folder 99999\JanSlip.pdf";

    var outputPath = GetDirectoryPathUpUntilFirstMatch(filePath, numberToFind);
}
```